# HTML CSS3 Jquery hover menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I'm trying to build a CSS3 hover menu. I want to hover an image (like first photo) and then appear my menu (like second photo) and also I want to hide the first image. Finally, I want to keep the hover state if cursor is on the menu.

[image]
[image]

Source code:

```js
$("#div-right img").hover(function(){
    $('#div-right a').removeClass('hidden');
    $("#div-right img").css({opacity: "0"});
},function(){
    $('#div-right a').addClass('hidden');
    $("#div-right img").css({opacity: "1"});    
});
```

```html
<div id="div-right"> 
    <a class="hidden" href="index.html" class="m1">HOME</a> 
    <a class="hidden" href="#" class="m2">ABOUT</a> 
    <a class="hidden" href="#" class="m3">CONTACT</a>
    <img src="images/menu-01.png" style="position:relative; right:30px;"> 
</div>
```

```css
#div-right a hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you provide some info. what is going wrong for instance? And what did you try to solve this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kv4tujyu/1/

Comment: It doesn't work properly. I cannot solve the problem.

Comment: @was Why you doesn't use only CSS to do this?

Comment: Because I cannot do it with only CSS. It doesn't work properly..

Comment: @was Please mark one of answer to finishing this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any js code to do that. Use `:hover` pseudoclass instead:

```css
#div-right{
  display: inline-block;
  /*border added for debug purpose*/
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  width: auto;
}

#div-right:hover>a{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#div-right:hover>img{
  display: none;
}

#div-right:hover>a{
  display: inline-block;
}

#div-right:hover>a:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#div-right>a{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-right"> 
  <a class="hidden" href="index.html" class="m1">HOME</a> 
  <a class="hidden" href="#" class="m2">ABOUT</a> 
  <a class="hidden" href="#" class="m3">CONTACT</a>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/fitdd0s.png"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed bit part of your code. You can use this code

```js
$("#div-right img, #div-right div").hover(function(){
    $("#div-right").addClass("hover");
},function(){
    $("#div-right").removeClass("hover");   
});
```

```css
#div-right div {
    display: none;
}

.hover > img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.hover > div {
    display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div-right"> 
    <img src="a"> 
    <div>
        <a href="#">HOME</a> 
        <a href="#">ABOUT</a> 
        <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
    </div>
</div>
```